# Using Tkinter in RPI via SSH throws ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg'

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

After reading many posts here, I still didn't find a solution to my problem.

**I'm using Raspberrypi and connecting to it via SSH.**  I'm trying to run python script which has Tkinter's functionality.

I've tried using the following two approaches from the previous discussions on this error w/o success:

**#1 Approach:** `export MPLBACKEND=TKAgg` before calling the script.

**#2 Approach:** using the following commands in the appropriate order:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**Any ideas how to solve this?**

**Error:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/pi/imu_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2500, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "/home/pi/imu_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 288, in switch_backend
    newbackend, required_framework, current_framework))
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

I've also added the script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import csv
import datetime
from mpu6050 import mpu6050

import matplotlib

matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class PlotRecAccGyro():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title('MPU6050 - Acceleration and Gyroscope')
        self.frame = Frame(self.parent)
        self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.parent.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.plot_trigger = True
        self.record_trigger = False

        self.var_all = IntVar()
        self.var_plot = IntVar()
        self.var_rec = IntVar()
        self.accgyro_chkbtn_state = []
        self.chkbtn_list = []

        # Call MPU6050 class
        self.mpu = mpu6050(0x68)

        # LabelFrame - Select components
        self.labelframe_comp = LabelFrame(self.frame, text='Select components')
        self.labelframe_comp.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=N + E + W + S)
        self.labelframe_comp.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

        # LabelFrame - Options to plot and record
        self.labelframe_opt = LabelFrame(self.frame, text='Options - Plot and Record')
        self.labelframe_opt.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=3, sticky=N + E + W + S)
        self.labelframe_opt.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

        # Checkbuttons - Acceleration
        for i, j in enumerate(['Acc_x', 'Acc_y', 'Acc_z']):
            self.var_acc = IntVar()
            self.acc_chkbtn = Checkbutton(self.labelframe_comp, text=j, variable=self.var_acc,
                                          command=self.components_chk_func, padx=5, pady=5)
            self.acc_chkbtn.grid(row=i, column=0)
            self.accgyro_chkbtn_state.append(self.var_acc)
            self.chkbtn_list.append(self.acc_chkbtn)

        # Checkbuttons - Gyroscope
        for i, j in enumerate(['Gyro_x', 'Gyro_y', 'Gyro_z']):
            self.var_gyro = IntVar()
            self.gyro_chkbtn = Checkbutton(self.labelframe_comp, text=j, variable=self.var_gyro,
                                           command=self.components_chk_func, padx=5, pady=5)
            self.gyro_chkbtn.grid(row=i, column=1)
            self.accgyro_chkbtn_state.append(self.var_gyro)
            self.chkbtn_list.append(self.gyro_chkbtn)

        # Checkbutton - All
        self.all_chkbtn = Checkbutton(self.labelframe_comp, text='All', variable=self.var_all,
                                      command=self.all_chk_func, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.all_chkbtn.grid(row=1, column=2)

        # Button - Plot
        self.plot_chkbtn = ttk.Button(self.labelframe_opt, text='Start Plotting',
                                      command=lambda: self.plot_start_stop('plt_btn'))
        self.plot_chkbtn.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N + E + W + S, padx=5, pady=10)
        self.plot_chkbtn.configure(state='disabled')

        # Button - Record to a file
        self.rec_chkbtn = ttk.Button(self.labelframe_opt, text='Start Recording',
                                     command=lambda: self.record_start_stop('rec_btn'))
        self.rec_chkbtn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N + E + W + S, padx=5, pady=10)
        self.rec_chkbtn.configure(state='disabled')

        # Label - File name
        self.rec_text = Label(self.labelframe_opt, text='to file (.csv)')
        self.rec_text.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N + E + W + S)

        # Entry - File name (Default name: SensorDataFile)
        self.file_name = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe_opt)
        self.file_name.insert(0, 'SensorDataFile')
        self.file_name.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=N + E + W + S, padx=5, pady=10)
        self.file_name.configure(state='disabled')

    # Function called on clicking on 'All' checkbutton
    def all_chk_func(self):
        if [i.get() for i in self.accgyro_chkbtn_state] != ([1] * 6):
            [i.set(1) for i in self.accgyro_chkbtn_state]
            self.plot_chkbtn.configure(state='normal')
        else:
            [i.set(0) for i in self.accgyro_chkbtn_state]
            self.plot_chkbtn.configure(state='disabled')

    # Function called on clicking on 'Record' checkbutton
    def rec_chk_func(self):
        if self.var_rec.get() == 1:
            self.file_name.configure(state='normal')
        else:
            self.file_name.configure(state='disabled')

    # Function called on clicking on acceleration or gyroscope checkbuttons
    def components_chk_func(self):
        if (0 in [i.get() for i in self.accgyro_chkbtn_state]):
            self.var_all.set(0)
        else:
            self.var_all.set(1)
        if (1 in [i.get() for i in self.accgyro_chkbtn_state]):
            self.plot_chkbtn.configure(state='normal')
        else:
            self.plot_chkbtn.configure(state='disabled')

    # Function called on clicking on 'Start plotting' or 'Stop plotting' button
    def plot_start_stop(self, btn_name):
        if self.plot_chkbtn['text'] == 'Start Plotting':
            self.plot_chkbtn['text'] = 'Stop Plotting'
            self.rec_chkbtn.configure(state='normal')
            self.file_name.configure(state='normal')
            self.all_chkbtn.configure(state='disabled')
            for i in self.chkbtn_list:
                i.configure(state='disabled')
            self.plot_trigger = True
            self.record_trigger = False

            n_plots = [i.get() for i in self.accgyro_chkbtn_state]
            acc_n_plots = n_plots[0:3]
            gyro_n_plots = n_plots[3:6]

            time_values = [i for i in range(50, 0, -1)]
            acc_values = [[0] * 50, [0] * 50, [0] * 50]
            gyro_values = [[0] * 50, [0] * 50, [0] * 50]

            plt.ion()
            acc_legends = ['Acc_x', 'Acc_y', 'Acc_z']
            gyro_legends = ['Gyro_x', 'Gyro_y', 'Gyro_z']
            if (1 in acc_n_plots) and (1 in gyro_n_plots):
                fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10, 7))
                ax[0].set_xlim(50, 0)
                ax[1].set_xlim(50, 0)
                ax[0].set_ylim([-30, 30])
                ax[1].set_ylim([-300, 300])
                for i, (title, y_axis_label) in enumerate(
                        [('Acceleration', 'Acceleration [m/s^2]'), ('Gyroscope', 'Angular velocity [deg/s]')]):
                    ax[i].set_title(title)
                    ax[i].set_ylabel(y_axis_label)
                    ax[i].set_xlabel('Latest 50 readings')
                    ax[i].grid()
                acc_plot_list = [ax[0].plot(time_values, acc_values[0], label=acc_legends[i])[0] if j == 1 else 0 for
                                 i, j in enumerate(acc_n_plots)]
                gyro_plot_list = [ax[1].plot(time_values, gyro_values[0], label=gyro_legends[i])[0] if j == 1 else 0 for
                                  i, j in enumerate(gyro_n_plots)]
                ax[0].legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
                ax[1].legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
            else:
                fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 4))
                ax.set_xlim(50, 0)
                if 1 in acc_n_plots:
                    acc_plot_list = [ax.plot(time_values, acc_values[0], label=acc_legends[i])[0] if j == 1 else 0 for
                                     i, j in enumerate(acc_n_plots)]
                    ax.set_title('Acceleration')
                    ax.set_xlabel('Latest 50 readings')
                    ax.set_ylabel('Acceleration [m/s^2]')
                    ax.set_ylim([-30, 30])
                    ax.grid()
                else:
                    gyro_plot_list = [ax.plot(time_values, gyro_values[0], label=gyro_legends[i])[0] if j == 1 else 0
                                      for i, j in enumerate(gyro_n_plots)]
                    ax.set_title('Gyroscope')
                    ax.set_xlabel('Latest 50 readings')
                    ax.set_ylabel('Angular velocity [deg/s]')
                    ax.set_ylim([-300, 300])
                    ax.grid()
                ax.legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
            plt.tight_layout()

            while self.plot_trigger:
                current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                accel_data = self.mpu.get_accel_data()
                gyro_data = self.mpu.get_gyro_data()
                current_acc = [accel_data['x'], accel_data['y'], accel_data['z']]
                current_gyro = [gyro_data['x'], gyro_data['y'], gyro_data['z']]

                for i, j in enumerate(acc_n_plots):
                    if j == 1:
                        acc_values[i].append(current_acc[i])
                        del acc_values[i][0]
                        acc_plot_list[i].set_ydata(acc_values[i])
                for i, j in enumerate(gyro_n_plots):
                    if j == 1:
                        gyro_values[i].append(current_gyro[i])
                        del gyro_values[i][0]
                        gyro_plot_list[i].set_ydata(gyro_values[i])

                if self.record_trigger:
                    row = [current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), current_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'),
                           current_time.strftime('%f')]
                    row = row + [i for i, j in
                                 zip(current_acc + current_gyro, [i.get() for i in self.accgyro_chkbtn_state]) if
                                 j == 1]
                    self.row_to_write.writerow(row)
                plt.draw()
                plt.pause(0.0001)
            plt.close('all')

        elif self.plot_chkbtn['text'] == 'Stop Plotting':
            self.plot_chkbtn['text'] = 'Start Plotting'
            self.rec_chkbtn.configure(state='disabled')
            self.file_name.configure(state='disabled')
            self.all_chkbtn.configure(state='normal')
            for i in self.chkbtn_list:
                i.configure(state='normal')
            self.plot_trigger = False
            self.record_trigger = False

    # Function called on clicking on 'Start writing' or 'Stop writing' button
    def record_start_stop(self, btn_name):
        if self.rec_chkbtn['text'] == 'Start Recording':
            self.rec_chkbtn['text'] = 'Stop Recording'
            self.plot_chkbtn.configure(state='disabled')
            self.file_name.configure(state='disabled')
            print('Started recording sensor data...')

            if self.file_name.get() != '':
                filename = self.file_name.get()
            else:
                filename = 'NoFileName'
            self.file_to_write = open(filename + '.csv', 'w')  # Open the file
            self.row_to_write = csv.writer(self.file_to_write, lineterminator='\n')
            column_titles = ['Date\n(YY:MM:DD)', 'Time\n(HH:MM:SS)', 'Time\n(Âµs)']
            column_titles = column_titles + [i for i, j in zip(
                ['Ax\n(m/s^2)', 'Ay\n(m/s^2)', 'Az\n(m/s^2)', 'Gx\n(deg/s)', 'Gy\n(deg/s)', 'Gz\n(deg/s)'],
                [i.get() for i in self.accgyro_chkbtn_state]) if j == 1]
            self.row_to_write.writerow(column_titles)
            self.record_trigger = True

        elif self.rec_chkbtn['text'] == 'Stop Recording':
            self.rec_chkbtn['text'] = 'Start Recording'
            self.plot_chkbtn.configure(state='normal')
            self.file_name.configure(state='normal')
            print('Stopped recording sensor data...')
            self.record_trigger = False
            self.file_to_write.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    plotrectool = PlotRecAccGyro(root)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

To download and use **MobaXterm**.